# how can i remove an append text that I inserted to the textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem in displaying an append word and remove string word value by clicking in the onitemselected in gridview.

I wanted like this:

```
 ___________
|           |
|   hello   |        =      hello  (CLICK)
|___________|  

 ___________
|           |
|   hello   |        =          (UNCLICK)
|___________|
```

for example: if i click item button hello it will display **"hello"** to the textview , when i click item button world it will display **"hello world"** in the text view but if i click again the item button hello it will remove the hello in the text view like this **"world"**

here is my onitemselect code:

```
ll.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                                if(position < noOfBtns) {

                                    String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                    String s2 = text_quiz.getText().toString();
                                    String [] s2_word = s2.split("\\s");
                                    List<String> str = Arrays.asList(s2_word);
                                    if(str.contains(selectedItem))
                                    {
                                        if(str.equals(selectedItem)) {
                                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_background);
                                            String rep = text_quiz.getText().toString().replace("\\b" + selectedItem + "\\b" + " ", "");
                                            String textToBeColored = "_";
                                            String htmlText = rep.replace(textToBeColored, "<font color='#6B3074'>" + textToBeColored + "</font>");
                                            text_quiz.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
                                        }
                                    }else {

                                                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons4);
                                                text_quiz.append(selectedItem + " ");

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

in my code i try to replace the same selected item to blank in Textview but when the button has the same word it will not display anymore. like the word **you** and **your** the replace method will find the same word and just replace it and also if i have a button item word **a** it will not display the code it will replace all letter a in the textview..

I really need help for this

Comment: `if(str.equals(selectedItem))` that's not gonna fly, as they are two different types.  why don't you just do `if(str.remove(selectedItem))` then rebuild the text from the remaining list items?

Comment: how can i rebuild the text can you give sample code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, from what you have there you can:

```
if (str.remove(selectedItem)) {
    // We know selectedItem was removed (the first, not sure if you have multiple)
    // so now we can just rebuild (here is a non stream version)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String st : str) {
        sb.append(textToBeColoured(str));  // Do whatever you want for whichever text
    }
    textQuiz.setText(Html.fromText(sb.toString());
} else {
   // Add like normal
}
```

You'll need to manage your HTML highlight functionality how you want, maybe change the for to include an index, or something else.  But at least in this `if()` block you know that `List<String> str` has had your text removed.